# JAXB: Mapping separate date and time elements to one property

Tags: java, calendar, jaxb

I'm working with a XML structure that looks like this:

```
<ROOT>
    <ELEM_A>
        <A_DATE>20100825</A_DATE>
        <A_TIME>141500</A_TIME>
        <!-- other elements, maybe also other or date/time combinations -->
        <STRING>ABC</STRING>
    <ELEM_A>
    <ELEM_B>
        <B_DATE>20100825</B_DATE>
        <B_TIME>153000</B_TIME>
        <NUM>123</NUM>
        <C_DATE>20100825</C_DATE>
        <C_TIME>154500</C_TIME>
    </ELEM_B>
</ROOT>
```

And I want to map date and time to a single `Date` or `Calendar` property in my bean. Is this possible using jaxb annotations? The class `javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter` looks like it might be able to do this, but I have to admit I don't fully understand its javadoc.

A workaround would be to create additional setters for the date and time strings that set the corresponding values in a `Calendar` property like this:

```
private Calendar calendar;

public void setDate(String date) {
    if (calendar == null) {
        calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    }
    calendar.set(YEAR, Integer.parseIn(date.substring(0, 4)));
    calendar.set(MONTH, Integer.parseIn(date.substring(4, 6))-1);
    calendar.set(DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseIn(date.substring(6, 8)));
}

// Similar code for setTime
```

The problem (apart from the additional code) is that I can't always guarantee that the date is set before the time value, but I can't think of a specific example where this might give worng results.

Any examples for an annotation based solution or improvements / counter examples for the code above are appreciated.

**Edit:** I went with the second answer given by [Blaise Doughan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383861/blaise-doughan), but modified his DateAttributeTransformer to be more flexible and not expect the field name to contain the string "DATE". The field names are taken from the XmlWriterTransformer annotations on the field:

```
@Override
public Object buildAttributeValue(Record record, Object instance, Session session) {
    try {
        String dateString = null;
        String timeString = null;

        String dateFieldName = null;
        String timeFieldName = null;
        // TODO: Proper Exception handling
        try {
            XmlWriteTransformers wts = instance.getClass().getDeclaredField(mapping.getAttributeName()).getAnnotation(XmlWriteTransformers.class);
            for (XmlWriteTransformer wt : wts.value()) {
                String fieldName = wt.xpath();
                if (wt.transformerClass() == DateFieldTransformer.class) {
                    dateFieldName = fieldName;
                } else {
                    timeFieldName = fieldName;
                }
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        } catch (SecurityException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }

        for(DatabaseField field : mapping.getFields()) {
            XMLField xfield = (XMLField)field;
            if(xfield.getXPath().equals(dateFieldName)) {
                dateString = (String) record.get(field);
            } else {
                timeString = (String) record.get(field);
            }
        }
        return yyyyMMddHHmmss.parseObject(dateString + timeString);
    } catch(ParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the JAXB RI (Metro), you could use the MOXy JAXB implementation (I'm the tech lead).  It has some extensions that will make mapping this scenario fairly easy.

**jaxb.properties**

To use MOXy as your JAXB implementation you need to add a file named jaxb.properties in the same package as your model classes with the following entry:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Root**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="ROOT")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    @XmlElement(name="ELEM_A")
    private ElemA elemA;

    @XmlElement(name="ELEM_B")
    private ElemB elemB;

}
```

**ElemA**

We can leverate @XmlTransformation.  It is similar in concept to XmlAdapter, but easier to share among mappings.

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlReadTransformer;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlTransformation;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlWriteTransformer;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlWriteTransformers;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ElemA {

    @XmlTransformation
    @XmlReadTransformer(transformerClass=DateAttributeTransformer.class)
    @XmlWriteTransformers({
        @XmlWriteTransformer(xpath="A_DATE/text()", transformerClass=DateFieldTransformer.class),
        @XmlWriteTransformer(xpath="A_TIME/text()", transformerClass=TimeFieldTransformer.class),
    })
    public Date aDate;

    @XmlElement(name="STRING")
    private String string;
}
```

**ElemB**

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlReadTransformer;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlTransformation;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlWriteTransformer;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlWriteTransformers;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ElemB {

    @XmlTransformation
    @XmlReadTransformer(transformerClass=DateAttributeTransformer.class)
    @XmlWriteTransformers({
        @XmlWriteTransformer(xpath="B_DATE/text()", transformerClass=DateFieldTransformer.class),
        @XmlWriteTransformer(xpath="B_TIME/text()", transformerClass=TimeFieldTransformer.class),
    })
    private Date bDate;

    @XmlElement(name="NUM")
    private int num;

    @XmlTransformation
    @XmlReadTransformer(transformerClass=DateAttributeTransformer.class)
    @XmlWriteTransformers({
        @XmlWriteTransformer(xpath="C_DATE/text()", transformerClass=DateFieldTransformer.class),
        @XmlWriteTransformer(xpath="C_TIME/text()", transformerClass=TimeFieldTransformer.class),
    })
    private Date cDate;

}
```

**DateAttributeTransformer**

The attribute transformer is responsible for unmarshalling the Date object.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.DatabaseField;
import org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.foundation.AbstractTransformationMapping;
import org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.transformers.AttributeTransformer;
import org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.Record;
import org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.Session;

public class DateAttributeTransformer implements AttributeTransformer {

    private AbstractTransformationMapping mapping;
    private SimpleDateFormat yyyyMMddHHmmss = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");

    public void initialize(AbstractTransformationMapping mapping) {
        this.mapping = mapping;
    }

    public Object buildAttributeValue(Record record, Object instance, Session session) {
        try {
            String dateString = null;
            String timeString = null;

            for(DatabaseField field : mapping.getFields()) {
                if(field.getName().contains("DATE")) {
                    dateString = (String) record.get(field);
                } else {
                    timeString = (String) record.get(field);
                }
            }
            return yyyyMMddHHmmss.parseObject(dateString + timeString);
        } catch(ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

**DateFieldTransformer**

The field transformers are responsible for marshalling the Date object.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.foundation.AbstractTransformationMapping;
import org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.transformers.FieldTransformer;
import org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.Session;

public class DateFieldTransformer implements FieldTransformer {

    private AbstractTransformationMapping mapping;
    private SimpleDateFormat yyyyMMdd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

    public void initialize(AbstractTransformationMapping mapping) {
        this.mapping = mapping;
    }

    public Object buildFieldValue(Object instance, String xPath, Session session) {
        Date date = (Date) mapping.getAttributeValueFromObject(instance);
        return yyyyMMdd.format(date);
    }

}
```

**TimeFieldTransformer**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.foundation.AbstractTransformationMapping;
import org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.transformers.FieldTransformer;
import org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.Session;

public class TimeFieldTransformer implements FieldTransformer {

    private AbstractTransformationMapping mapping;
    private SimpleDateFormat HHmmss = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss");

    public void initialize(AbstractTransformationMapping mapping) {
        this.mapping = mapping;
    }

    public Object buildFieldValue(Object instance, String xPath, Session session) {
        Date date = (Date) mapping.getAttributeValueFromObject(instance);
        return HHmmss.format(date);
    }

}
```

**Sample Program**

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);
        System.out.println(jc);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum41/input.xml");
        Root root = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**XML Document**

```
<ROOT> 
    <ELEM_A> 
        <A_DATE>20100825</A_DATE> 
        <A_TIME>141500</A_TIME>
        <!-- other elements, maybe also other or date/time combinations --> 
        <STRING>ABC</STRING> 
    </ELEM_A> 
    <ELEM_B> 
        <B_DATE>20100825</B_DATE> 
        <B_TIME>153000</B_TIME>
        <NUM>123</NUM> 
        <C_DATE>20100825</C_DATE> 
        <C_TIME>154500</C_TIME>
    </ELEM_B> 
</ROOT>
```

The code as shown above requires EclipseLink 2.2 currently under development.  A nightly builds are available here:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php

The current released version of EclipseLink 2.1 supports the above, but with a slightly different configuration.  We can discuss the appropriate setup if you are interested in exploring this option.

Comment: Thanks again for the extensive answer, I will give EclipseLink MOXy a try.

Comment: Some additional details are available on my blog:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/xmltransformation-going-beyond.html

Comment: Found some time to try this out and this works fine in my tests. I did some modifications to DateAttributeTransformer to replace the `contains` check with something equally hacky but more flexible. I will add the modified source to the question.

Answer (score 5):

XmlAdapter is the right approach:

**Class with Date property**

```
import java.util.Date;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement(name="ROOT")
public class Root {

    private Date date;

    @XmlElement(name="ELEM")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

}
```

**The implementation of XmlAdapter**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<AdaptedDate, Date> {

    private SimpleDateFormat yyyyMMdd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    private SimpleDateFormat HHmmss = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss");
    private SimpleDateFormat yyyyMMddHHmmss = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");

    @Override
    public Date unmarshal(AdaptedDate v) throws Exception {
        String dateString = v.getDate() + v.getTime();
        return yyyyMMddHHmmss.parse(dateString);
    }

    @Override
    public AdaptedDate marshal(Date v) throws Exception {
        AdaptedDate adaptedDate = new AdaptedDate();
        adaptedDate.setDate(yyyyMMdd.format(v));
        adaptedDate.setTime(HHmmss.format(v));
        return adaptedDate;
    }

}
```

**The adapted Date object**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class AdaptedDate {

    private String date;
    private String time;

    @XmlElement(name="DATE")
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="TIME")
    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

}
```

**Sample program**

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        File xml = new File("input.xml");
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Root root = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }
}
```

**XML Document**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT>
    <ELEM>
        <DATE>20100825</DATE>
        <TIME>141500</TIME>
    </ELEM>
</ROOT>
```

For more information see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html

Comment: Thanks, great example of XmlAdapter, much clearer than the HashMap example from the javadoc. My example xml was a bit to simplistic, I can actually have other elements and other date/time combinations in that element too. Would it be possible to adapt two date/time elements if they are not wrapped in another element? I will update the question with a more complete example.

Comment: I have submitted a second answer that describes how this can be done using MOXy JAXB extensions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565621/jaxb-mapping-separate-date-and-time-elements-to-one-property/3567927#3567927.